# WYGWAM double wrapping email links when emailProtection is set to encode

Tags: wygwam, encode

I have an editor configuration set up using emailProtection. emailProtection is set to Encode. If the user adds an email link in the WYSIWYG editor, when it is rendered in the page, it has the original link and then that one is wrapped in another obfuscated one. I would have expected it to replace the original one with the obfuscated one. Am I missing something in the settings? Here is an example of the output.

```
<a href="javascript:void(location.href='mailto:'+String.fromCharCode(106,122,105,101,103,108,101,114,64,116,101,97,109,99,102,97,46,111,114,103))"><a href="mailto:me@here.org">me@here.org</a></a>
```